# SOAP Service does not read a requested data after migration to the new Spring Boot

Tags: java, soap

I'm having a problem with a SOAP service after migrating to the new Spring Boot.
The old SOAP service worked with the jaxws-spring component. The service definition was:

```
@WebMethod
@WebResult(name = "check", partName = "response", targetNamespace = NAMESPACE_URI)
public SafetyCheck check(@WebParam(name = "checkRequest", partName = "request", targetNamespace = NAMESPACE_URI) SafetyCheckRequest safetyCheckRequest) {
```

Now after the migration I had to get rid of the jaxws-spring due to incompatibility and after the upgrade the service looks like this:

```
@PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "check")
@ResponsePayload
public JAXBElement<SafetyCheck> check(@RequestPayload JAXBElement<SafetyCheckRequest> safetyCheckRequest) {
```

The wsdl file has not changed. The relevant part is as follows:

```
    <xs:element name="check" type="tns:check" />
    <xs:element name="checkResponse" type="tns:checkResponse" />
    <xs:complexType name="check">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element form="qualified" minOccurs="0" name="checkRequest" type="tns:safetyCheckRequest" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="safetyCheckRequest">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="tns:baseRequest">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="checkToPerform" type="xs:string" />
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="parameters" type="xs:string" />
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
```

The SOAP UI generates a request from the WSDL, which is exactly the same as the previous one:

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <S:Body>
        <ns2:check xmlns:ns2="http://.....">
            <ns2:checkRequest>
                <checkToPerform>WARNINGS</checkToPerform>
                <parameters>
                    ...
                </parameters>
            </ns2:checkRequest>
        </ns2:check>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

But now the service receives an empty request value. After some testing I found that it will work correctly after removing ns2:checkRequest:

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <S:Body>
        <ns2:check xmlns:ns2="http://.....">
                <checkToPerform>WARNINGS</checkToPerform>
                <parameters>
                    ...
                </parameters>
        </ns2:check>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

Perhaps the reason is that the old version had a name definition: @WebParam(name = "checkRequest"... .
How can I do the same with the new one?